# Program startup is slow

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, avast

Recently I have installed Avast antivirus and uninstalled a few VAIO related programs. After this, startup of programs is taking more time than usual. How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an alternative antivirus, personally I use AVG at the moment (made a lot of switches between AVG and AVAST). I had the same problem with AVAST but I don't have this problem with AVG.

You can also add every .exe of your programs to the AVAST Whitelist because AVAST scans every application before opening, of course this will be a lot of work and will be less safe.

So consider to try AVG

Comment: Thanks for the info. Your are right. I have disabled scanning exe files in avast, now everything is normal. And as far as I know AVG is not that good as Avast in protecting system.

Comment: The fact is neither are really that good compared to some of the paid solutions.